# Redirect to a children route

Tags: angular, typescript, routes, children

I have two components: students-list and student-details

I would like that when I launch the app, I land on `localhost:4200/students`

When I click on the details, I would like to arrive on `localhost:4200/students/1/details`  (1 = student id)

I am redirected to `localhost:4200/students` when I put `localhost:4200`
but when I click on a detail I am not redirected. My button does this:

```
details(student: Student) {
    console.log('details clicked!')
    this.router.navigate([student.id, 'details']);
  }
```

and my routes (app-routing.module.ts) are like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '**' , redirectTo: 'students', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'students', component: StudentsListComponent, children: [
    { path: '', component: StudentsListComponent },
    { path: ':id/details', component: StudentDetailsComponent }
  ]},
  ];
```

I don't understand where the problem is coming from.
I may have misunderstood how childrens work.

Can you help me ?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change your routes order to -

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { 
      path: 'students', component: StudentsListComponent, 
      children: [
         { path: '', component: StudentsListComponent },
         { path: ':id/:details', component: StudentDetailsComponent }
      ]
  },
  { path: '**' , redirectTo: 'students', pathMatch: 'full'},
];
```

In details method

```
details(student: Student) {
    console.log('details clicked!')
    this.router.navigate(['students', {id: student.id, details: 'details'}]);
  }
```

And see if that is working

Comment: It doesn't work. When I click on a detail, I stay on localhost:4200/students

Maybe it's the navigate button that has a problem?

Comment: change next code in details method `this.router.navigate(['students', {id: student.id, details: 'details' }]);`

Comment: I arrive on `localhost: 4200/students;id=1;details=details`
and the page remains that of ` /students`
if I put ` this.router.navigate (['students', {id: student.id}, 'details']); `
  it doesn't work to :(

Comment: Put your code on StackBlitz so that we can take a look @Nitneuq